# String to Double conversion nil in different region Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

There is a text field

```
@IBOutlet weak var txt: UITextField!
```

When I tried to convert the value of txt into Double its worked fine in US region.

For example

```
let magicNumber = Double(txt.text ?? "0.0")
```

If I type 12 UITextField then 12 assigned on magicNumber

Then I changed the region to Germany.

[image]

```
let magicNumber = Double(txt.text ?? "0.0")
```

If I type 12,8 UITextField then the magicNumber is nil.

I need a correct double value like : 12.8

How could I achieve this? Please suggest to me the correct way.

Comment: Use [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/) to convert numbers to and from user input, not `Double(string)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful handling of localized numeric strings

```
let inputString = "12,8" 
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current // Locale(identifier: "de")
let number = formatter.number(from: inputString) 
print(number) // 12.8
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are dealing with relates to the default .current Locale, and localisation of the application. The .decimalPad first looks at the app localisation, and if it's not localised in the .current region language, it defaults to the en_YourLanguage format. Therefore, your .current formatted number may have "." separator, but you'll see "," on your .decimalPad.

Example:

- My region: *Ukraine*
- My app isLocalized: *false*
- The locale on .numberPad: *"en_UA"*
- The .current locale if formatted: *"uk_UA"*